# Using PrintWriter while downloading a file

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a requirement, where i need to process a set of files and create a compressed zip file out of it and then use it for download. I am using a Servlet for downloading that file, but the download takes quite sometime. So i want the user to know that the servlet is processing the request through a print writer output messsage instead of showing him a blank screen.But everytime i use a printwriter to write something to the screen, the message takes a lot of time to show on the screen and the file doesnt download.
How can i achieve this? Any ides? 
Thanks.

Here's my code

```
OutputStream oStream = null;
    DataInputStream dInput = null;
    File file = new File(("PATH"));
    int length = 0;
    try{
        DownloadServerLogs.processLogs();
        oStream = res.getOutputStream();
        res.setContentType("application/zip");
        res.setContentLength((int)file.length());
        res.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                         "attachment;filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"" );
        byte[] bbuf = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
        dInput = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        while ((dInput != null) && ((length = dInput.read(bbuf)) != -1))
        {
            oStream.write(bbuf,0,length);
        }
        dInput.close();
        oStream.flush();
        oStream.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Utility.getLogger().error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

Comment: What language/platform is this in? Your tags make no sense.

Comment: servlet, so java maybe? /shrug

Comment: @edgerunner Sorry, my mistake, thats java code. I modified the tags.

Comment: Makes sense now. I removed my downvote. I also took the liberty of removing some of your tags. They were keyword-like rather than tag-like. I also added JSP as a tag, I assume that's your platform.

Comment: @edgerunner Thanks for the effort. Starting now i will make sure that i will use only relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

I guess its better to display the message to the client by using something like Javascript (assuming you are using AJAX to invoke the servlet).

Comment: I wasnt using an Ajax call. I am hitting the servlet directly. This is just a small utility for processing error logs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's probably not that safe to do it that way. I'd have a look at the answer below. Not that it's your exact problem, but might be similar.

[Most efficient way to create InputStream from OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225909/most-efficient-way-to-create-inputstream-from-outputstream)

Effectively, you are reading and writing on the same thread and my guess is that with the addition of the PrintWriter you are getting deadlocked somewhere.