# Implementors of both OutputStream and InputStream for in-memory file transferring

Tags: java, java-io

I'm using an API (Jasper Reports) to generate PDFs and I'd like to do most of it in memory. I'm already able to get the generated file as an `OutputStream`, now I'm just looking for an implementor to use to keep things in memory which implements `InputStream` as well.

What class can I use which functions as both an `OutputStream` and an `InputStream` on in-memory data?

Comment: Similar to this question, resolved with `PipedInputStream`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225909/most-efficient-way-to-create-inputstream-from-outputstream

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ByteArrayInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) and [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html) to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

This Passage would be suitable more here, focusing on the dual implementation on both of **Input and Output**.

http://blog.ostermiller.org/convert-a-java-writer-to-a-reader/

As metioned in the article, the `PipedReader` and `PipedWriter` would be a awesome solution, and the `Circular Buffer` provided from [Ostermiller.util](http://ostermiller.org/utils/src/CircularCharBuffer.java.html) as well if you are allowed to import another dependency.