# Bitmap for an ImageView is null in Android ( MySQL DataBase)

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am saving byteArray of an image in MySQL Database, and Retrieving from Databses then coverting string to byteArray then byteArray to get Bitmap. But Bitmap is Null i have tried a lot of codes but still NULL.
Saving an Image

```
private String imageviewtobyte(ImageView view){
        Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable) view.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        ConvertImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return ConvertImage;

    }
```

Getting an Image

```
 imgData=result;
    byte[] byteArray = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Bitmap bMap = null;
    bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray,0,byteArray.length);
    testimg.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Looking for experts to getting exact error with solution.

Comment: Have you checked the ConvertImage ?does it contains string form of image?

Comment: `Saving an Image`. That code does not upload an image and save somewhere in a MySQL database at all.

Comment: i have give here only concrete code values are going right and coming right. i checked by debugging but problem is Bitmap conversion is not workinggg

Answer (score 0):

```
//check result object it is null or not
if(result != null){
     imgData = result;
     Bitmap bitmap = StringToBitMap(imgData);
     if(bitmap != null){
         testimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
     }
}   

/**
 * @param encodedString
 * @return bitmap (from given string)
 */
public static Bitmap StringToBitMap(String encodedString){
    try{
        byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(encodedString,Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: i have already checked result is not null, but let me check this by implementing your method

Comment: use this link to check whether your String is valid bsae64 or not http://www.askapache.com/online-tools/base64-image-converter/

Comment: This code is the same as that from OP. And also if the bitmap is null you can assign it to the image view.

Comment: String is valid i have checked now these lines skipped during debugging

Bitmap bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length);
        return bitmap;

Comment: greenapps u r right, according to you what is the main issue then??

Comment: Uploading. Saving. Retrieving. Downloading. To name a few.

Answer (score 0):

Base64String is not working well for the large bitmap. So first you have to decrease the size of a bitmap before converting it to the base64String. I attached a code for decreasing the size of the bitmap.
You can use maxWidth = 960.0 and maxheight = 1280.0 in this code.

```
    public Bitmap GetBitmap(Bitmap finalimage) {
    int actualHeight = finalimage.getHeight();
    int actualWidth = finalimage.getWidth();
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        }
    }
    finalimage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(finalimage, actualWidth, actualHeight, false);
    return finalimage;
}
```

Comment: `Base64String in not working well for the large bitmap. `. ??? For a bitmap? It is only used on a byte array. Never heard of limitations for an array.

Comment: It's weird but it is true. You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28641704/converting-bitmap-to-base64-string-causes-outofmemory-error) link.

Comment: size is not an issue  dhruv gangani  i checked this

Comment: Exactly, size was the main issue. Thank You Very Much dhruv