# Standara way for passing image from android to php server

Tags: php, android, server

I'm trying to pass an image from Android application to php server.
I searched about that, I have two ways:

- Sending by Multipart
- Encode to Base64

I'm using Volley, I know about both but I don't know which is better for implementation.
Can you tell me which is standard and better?

Comment: I am not sure about the usage of volley for Multipart.

Comment: @ShaluTD  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32240177/working-post-multipart-request-with-volley-and-without-httpentity

Comment: Thanks for your information. Why don't you go with retrofit?

Comment: @ShaluTD  your welcome. Excuse me, retrofit to what? I don't exactly you mean.

Comment: I think retrofit is better than volley.

Comment: I see, Than you so much

Comment: `Decode to Base64` ??? You mean `encode base64`.

Comment: @greenapps encode

Answer (score 0):

Do not go with the base64 string since it may give you crash if it exceeds the limit. Better option to use the Multipart, it is reliable and safe.

Comment: exceeds limit of what ?

Comment: I mean it will throw out of memory error, but we can solve through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579874/out-of-memory-when-encoding-file-to-base64. anyway I recommend multipart.