# File(s) and InputStream/OutputStream

Tags: java

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I am doing multistep processing on some data I am receiving with a java Servlet.  The current process I have is that I input the files to a server using Apache File Upload and convert them to a `File`. Then once `input1` is populated with data, I run through a flow similar to this (where the process functions are xsl transforms):

```
File input1 = new File(FILE_NAME);  // <---this is populated with data
File output1 = new File(TEMP_FILE); // <---this is the temporary file

InputStream read = new FileInputStream(input1); 
OuputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output1);

process1ThatReadsProcessesOutputs( read, out);

out.close();
read.close();

//this is basically a repeat of the above process!
File output2 = new File(RESULT_FILE);  // <--- This is the result file 
InputStream read1 = new FileInputStream(output1);
OutputStream out1 = new FileOutputStream(output2);
Process2ThatReadsProcessesOutputs( read1, out1);
read1.close();
out1.close();
…
```

So my question is if there is a better way to do this so I do not have to create those temporary `File`s and recreate streams to those `File`s? (I am assuming I am incurring a decent performace penatly)

I saw this [Most Efficient Way to create InputStream from OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225909/most-efficient-way-to-create-inputstream-from-outputstream) but I am not sure if this is the best route to go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `FileOutputStream` to `ByteArrayInputStream` vice/versa.

Example:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());
```

Comment: I reviewed the docs on BufferedStream... Is this line `InputStream read1 = new FileInputStream(out);` using the `FileInputStream(FileDescriptor fdObj)` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why are you converting the [FileItem](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileUpload.html) retrieved with Apache Commons if you don't really needed. You can use the same `InputStream` that each `FileItem` has to using and read the content of the uploaded file:

```
// create/retrieve a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = ...;

// parse the request
List<FileItem> items = (List<FileItem>) upload.parseRequest(request);

/* get the FileItem from the List. Yes, it's not a best practice because you must verify 
   how many you receive, and check everything is ok, etc. 
   Let's suppose you've done it */
//...
FileItem item = items.get(0); 

// get the InputStrem to read the contents of the file 
InputStream is = item.getInputStream();
```

So finally, you can use the `InputStream` object to read the uploaded stream sent by the client avoiding unnecessary instantiations.

And yes, it's really recommended to use Buffered clases like `BufferedInputStream` and `BufferedOutputStream`.

The other idea could be to avoid `FileOutputStream` (the middle one) and replace it with `ByteArrayOutputStream` if you don't need to be written in disk (always is slower than working in memory).

Answer (score 0):

Java 9 brings a new answer to the question:

```
// All bytes from an InputStream at once
byte[] result = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)
    .readAllBytes();

// Directly redirect an InputStream to an OutputStream
new ByteArrayInputStream(buf)
    .transferTo(System.out);
```