# Using Ion write(outputStream)

Tags: android, networking, androidasync-koush, ion-koush

I'm not understanding how the write(outputStream) method is supposed to be used in Ion.  My goal is to get an InputStream that I can feed directly into Jackson like so:

```
Response<OutputStream> response = Ion.with(context, "http://example.com/mydata.json").write(outputStream).withResponse().get();
MyModel m = jacksonJsonMapper.convertValue(inputStream, MyModel.class);
```

But I'm lost as to where to get the input and output streams, and how to connect them to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured out a solution based on this answer: [Most efficient way to create InputStream from OutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225909/most-efficient-way-to-create-inputstream-from-outputstream#answer-1226031)

Looks like I want to use a PipedOutputStream and PipedInputStream.  Because we're now blocking on reading from the InputStream, I no longer want to block on the Ion call, so I removed the .get().  The final code looks something like:

```
PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream();
PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream);
Ion.with(context, "http://example.com/mydata.json").write(outputStream).withResponse();
MyModel m = jacksonJsonMapper.convertValue(inputStream, MyModel.class);
```

Comment: You do not need the withResponse() call, that's only useful if you want the headers, etc.

Comment: Also, I think that jackson call will block on inputStream, so be careful that it is not being done on the UI thread.

I'll see if I can add an asStream() method that will give you an easier way to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I do want headers, mainly to check the status code.
Yes, that Jackson call will block on the network, but that's what I'm looking for. I'm calling this all in a background thread already.

An asStream() method might be nice, but it'd have to block, unlike all the other as*() methods, so that might be inconsistent.