# get OutputStream from BufferedReader

Tags: java, iostream

I have two object:

```
BufferedReader br;
CMSSignedData cms;
```

I have to write cms content to `BufferedReader`
cms has this method:

```
 cms.getSignedContent().write(OutputStream os);
```

But how to get the `OutputStream` from `BufferedReader`?

This is my attemp:

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream os=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        cms.getSignedContent().write(os);
        InputStream is=new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray());  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

But I don't think this is the best way.

Comment: Should this be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: I agree with @Mex. If your code is working, but you are just hoping for a more elegant solution, codereview might be a good choice.

Comment: That looks fine to me.

Comment: There is a PipedInputStream/PipedOutputStream, and PipedReader/PipedWriter classes available in the API, although I don't see them used very much so I think they have fallen out of favor, perhaps.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a piped input/output stream.

```
PipedOutputStream os = new PipedOutputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new PipedInputStream(os)));
cms.getSignedContent().write(os);
```

Take note of piet.t's comment on threads however.

As well as check the relevant APIs docs:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html

Comment: I don't see how your output and input are connected in this example.

Comment: This would have been my suggestion too. But keep in mind that `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream` should live in different threads to avoid deadlocks. But any clean solution either has to make use of some explicit buffer-space or two threads (one for reading, one for writing).

Comment: @Duncan there was a typo in code, corrected it.

Comment: I don't want to use two thread. May I use Piped? Why do you think this is better than a raw ByteArray? Thanks

Comment: This post has an nice asnwer that makes the threading simple. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225909/most-efficient-way-to-create-inputstream-from-outputstream

Comment: @Tobia When using the byte-array you dump all data to be transfered into the heap while using PipedStreams data can be passed from Stream to Stream byte by byte, at the speed it is generated or consumed. That might not be worth the trouble for small data, but think of Streams of hundreds of Megabytes...