# How to write xml file to AWS

Tags: java, xml, amazon-s3

Currently, I am writing xml file on local directory using `XMLOutputFactory` which accept `OutputStream` as a parameter. But Now I need to write xml file to AWS S3 without writing on local. I don't have local directory access.

But I am not getting "How I can write xml file to AWS S3?".

Here is my code which write xml in local directory.

```
File file = new File(storeFilename);
DataOutputStream stream = null;
stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
// Create new instance of XML straem writer
XMLOutputFactory inputFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();

try {
    XMLStreamWriter writer = inputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(
                graphMLOutputStream, "UTF8");

    writer.writeStartDocument();
    writer.writeStartElement(GRAPHML);
    writer.writeAttribute(XMLNS, GRAPHML_XMLNS);
   }
```

I know how to put files on AWS S3 using `PutObjectRequest()` by giving file name or inputstream as a parameter.

```
// send request to S3 to create folder
PutObjectRequest putobjreq = new PutObjectRequest(
                CAWSConstants.BUCKETNAME, file.getName(), file);            
// put graphml file to aws
s3Client.putObject(putobjreq);
```

But I don't know how to covert xml in to inputstream using xmlWriter. Which I can sent to `PutObjectRequest`.

Please give me hint or reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `FileOutputStream` you should be able to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Then refer to [How to upload a Java OutputStream to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805518/how-to-upload-a-java-outputstream-to-aws-s3).