# How to upload PowerPoint in s3 in Java?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-poi, powerpoint

The [POI PowerPoint api](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XMLSlideShow.html) has a method [`write(outputstream)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#write-java.io.OutputStream-).

But I see S3Client has an api which only accepts an `InputStream` to upload files: `putObject(bucket, fileKey, inputStream, objectMetadata)`

Could someone please suggest the best way to upload the PowerPoint file to s3?

1. Should I temporarily write on the disk using the `powerpointApi.write(FileOutputStream)` and then upload this file to S3 using the `putObject(bucket, fileKey, file)` or `putObject(bucket, fileKey, inputStream)`?
2. Or should I write the PowerPoint to `OutputStream` using `powerpointApi.write(FileOutputStream)` and then convert the output stream to input stream using this accepted answer on stackoverflow ([How to upload a Java OutputStream to AWS S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805518/how-to-upload-a-java-outputstream-to-aws-s3)) and then write to s3 using `putObject(bucket, fileKey, inputStream)`?

Also could someone please explain the pros and cons of both these approaches?

Also if someone has better solution please help.

Comment: It is your decision and nothing which can be discussed here since this is not a discussion forum. If I could using temporary files, then I would do this. But this will not always be possible. And if not, then a byte array in memory filled using `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then reread using `ByteArrayInputStream` would be the solution.

Comment: https://blog.ostermiller.org/convert-java-outputstream-inputstream